# Java do while or .equals logic problems

Tags: java

Ok so I'm still pretty much a nub to Java, I'm doing my best but I just cant figure out why this wont work. I previously worked in c++ but when I changed universities I had to change languages and now I've got some catching up to do, I've got this fairly simple code here, but either the logic in my do while loop is off or I'm not using `.equals()` properly, though I have googled a lot and tried many different variations of the problem.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid mode: ");
    mode = input.nextLine();
    mode = mode.toUpperCase();
    // test statement 1 boolean baa = !mode.trim().equals("DEC");
    // test statement 2 System.out.println(baa);
} while ( mode.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("DEC")
    || !"HEX".trim().equals(mode)
    || !"OCT".trim().equals(mode)
    || !"BIN".trim().equals(mode)); //the error is somewhere in here
```

I have been testing it and it ticks to true if I say input "DEC" but somehow I still can't exit the loop. Sorry if my problem is really silly.

Comment: We can't fix code if we don't know what it should do, and what it does instead. But what's sure is that if something is equal to DEC, it will always be different from HEX, OCT and BIN. So your while clause makes no sense.

Comment: What is `input`? A `Scanner`? Also, why do you `trim()` string constants? Why `.equalsIgnoreCase()` and not just `.equals()`?

Comment: I think it would make more sense to have a boolean variable calculated before the `while` and then use that in the `while condition`, rather than this bloated mess that even you don't understand anymore. :P

Comment: `do-while` in Java has exactly the same semantics as C++. You just forgot to negate `mode.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("DEC")`

Comment: @Zhuinden Or even better, put all your constants in a constant collection and use `contains()`.

Comment: @biziclop once you'd see the extreme duplication at the calculation of the boolean, that would indeed be the next logical step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will never come out of the loop because of your condition. This line alone will ensure that you will never ever come out of the loop.

```
!"HEX".trim().equals(mode)  || !"OCT".trim().equals(mode)
```

If you have just `!"HEX".trim().equals(mode)` you can come out by giving `HEX` but if you have both giving `HEX` will make `!"OCT".trim().equals(mode)` it true and giving OCT will make `!"HEX".trim().equals(mode)` to true.

So, Ideally I would assume that you want to come out if user didn't give both then right operator would be `&&` intead of `||` in the while condition. As there are multiple conditions, you have to carefully validate if that works.

Assuming you want to be in loop as long as it is DEC but not (HEX or OCT or BIN, or anything else) below code should work.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid mode: ");
    mode = input.nextLine();
    mode = mode.toUpperCase();
} while (mode.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("DEC"));
```

However if your requirement is to ensure that given mode is `DEC`, Below code will work. This loop will keep asking the user until he enters DEC

```
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid mode: ");
    mode = input.nextLine();
    mode = mode.toUpperCase();
} while (!"DEC".trim().equals(mode)));
```

So, my suggestion would be that you analyse your need carefully.

Comment: That depends on your need but yes && would ensure that it comes out  on certain conditions

Comment: Your answer is right but it does not give the OP a fix

Comment: @Dici I think he just has to change the `||` to `&&`and it should work. The negated booleans can be confusing due to the `De Morgan` rule.

Comment: @Zhuinden Right, but it does not appear in the provided answer

Comment: @Dici Yes, I was in the process of updating the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can clarify your exit condition with the following:

```
Collection<String> validMode = Arrays.asList("DEC", "BIN", "HEX", "OCT");
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid mode: ");
    mode = input.nextLine();
    mode = mode.trim().toUpperCase();
} while (!validMode.contains(mode));
```

**Edit:** for those who likes HashSet wrapping.

1. Yes, it would be correct to wrap validMode = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(...))

But

2. It is more code to write/read. A bit, but it breaks paradigm "less code - better code".
3. It is **wrong** to argue such improvement with algorithms complexity theory, because in the current case we have no variable N, we have **constant N = 4**.
4. It is "early optimization", while it was not proved this code is a bottleneck in your system.
5. There is no **actual measurements**, that such improvement would lead to better performance, **until you test** this change.

In practice it is often array-based list for N=4 works better, then the same size hash-set: faster + less memory consumption.

Comment: Why not use a HashSet instead? It's O(1). Won't make a big difference here, but still semantically more correct.

Comment: For this question it doesn't matter. My example is simpler for understanding (less code).

Comment: All the code you would need to add is a constructor call around the list : `Set<String> validModes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(...))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're thinking in terms of "repeat...until" loop.

In pseudo-code, it would be something like

```
repeat {
   read x
} until (x==ASC or x==HEX or x==DEC or x==BIN)
```

Your construction is using a "do...while" loop, which is exactly the opposite of "repeat...until", so you have to use deMorgan to change the condition, like this

```
do {
   read x
} while (x!=ASC and x!=HEX and x!=DEC and x!=BIN)
```

Then you can exit the loop when you find one of the values you want.

Of course, it's easier to maintain your condition using contains() as stated by ursa.